# How to split XML elements - php

Tags: php, html, xml, dom, domdocument

First of all, very beginner developer-trying-to-be here ^^. My first month at developing so, any suggestion will be appreciated.

I'm trying to develop an admin panel that inserts data into XML file from HTML form using PHP DOM.

Here is the outcome of the code.

```
<element>
<name> Name 1 </name>
<quantity> Quantity 1</quantity>
<name> Name 2</name>
<quantity> Quantity 2</quantity> 
<name> Name 3</name>
<quantity> Quantity 3</quantity>   
</element>
```

and here is the outcome that i want.

```
 <list>
   <ing>
    <name> Name </name>
    <quantity> Quantity </quantity>
   </ing>

   <ing>
    <name> Name </name>
    <quantity> Quantity </quantity> 
   </ing>

    <ing>
     <name> Name </name>
     <quantity> Quantity </quantity>   
    </ing>
  </list>
```

and lastly my php code: I'm using DOM.

```
   <?php
            if(isset($_REQUEST['ok'])){
              $xml = new DOMDocument ('1.0','UTF-8');

              $xml ->load('asd.xml');
              $rootTag = $xml ->getElementsByTagName('Settings')->item(0);


              $dataTag = $xml ->createElement('RecipeInfo');
              $dataTag->setAttribute("id",3);    //





              $sumTag = $xml ->createElement('RecipeSummary');
              $listTag = $xml ->createElement('RecipeIngredientsList');
              $ingTag = $xml ->createElement('RecipeIngredient');



    $aTag = $xml ->createElement('RecipeTitle',$_REQUEST['RecipeTitle']);
    $bTag = $xml ->createElement('RecipePicture',$_REQUEST['RecipePicture']);
    $cTag = $xml ->createElement('RecipeSummaryOrigin',$_REQUEST['RecipeSummaryOrigin']);
    $dTag = $xml ->createElement('RecipeSummaryPreparationTime',$_REQUEST['RecipeSummaryPreparationTime']);
    $eTag = $xml ->createElement('RecipeSummaryCookingTime',$_REQUEST['RecipeSummaryCookingTime']);
    $fTag = $xml ->createElement('RecipeSummaryPortions',$_REQUEST['RecipeSummaryPortions']);
    $gTag = $xml ->createElement('RecipeSummaryCalories',$_REQUEST['RecipeSummaryCalories']);
    $hTag = $xml ->createElement('RecipeSummaryDescription',$_REQUEST['RecipeSummaryDescription']);

    $jTag = $xml ->createElement('RecipeIngredientsName',$_REQUEST['RecipeIngredientsName']);
    $kTag = $xml ->createElement('RecipeIngredientsQuantity',$_REQUEST['RecipeIngredientsQuantity']);


$lTag = $xml ->createElement('iRecipeIngredientsName',$_REQUEST['iRecipeIngredientsName']);
    $mTag = $xml ->createElement('RecipeIngredientsQuantity',$_REQUEST['RecipeIngredientsQuantity']);

    $nTag = $xml ->createElement('uRecipeIngredientsName',$_REQUEST['uRecipeIngredientsName']);
    $oTag = $xml ->createElement('RecipeIngredientsQuantity',$_REQUEST['RecipeIngredientsQuantity']);

    $pTag = $xml ->createElement('dRecipeIngredientsName',$_REQUEST['dRecipeIngredientsName']);
    $rTag = $xml ->createElement('RecipeIngredientsQuantity',$_REQUEST['RecipeIngredientsQuantity']);

    $sTag = $xml ->createElement('bRecipeIngredientsName',$_REQUEST['bRecipeIngredientsName']);
    $tTag = $xml ->createElement('RecipeIngredientsQuantity',$_REQUEST['RecipeIngredientsQuantity']);


              $dataTag->appendChild($aTag);
              $dataTag->appendChild($bTag);
              $dataTag->appendChild($sumTag);
              $dataTag->appendChild($listTag);
              $listTag->appendChild($ingTag);

              //Recipe Summary Child'ları
              $sumTag->appendChild($cTag);
              $sumTag->appendChild($dTag);
              $sumTag->appendChild($eTag);
              $sumTag->appendChild($fTag);
              $sumTag->appendChild($gTag);
              $sumTag->appendChild($hTag);


              $ingTag->appendChild($jTag);
              $ingTag->appendChild($kTag);

              $ingTag->appendChild($lTag);
              $ingTag->appendChild($mTag);

              $ingTag->appendChild($nTag);
              $ingTag->appendChild($oTag);

              $ingTag->appendChild($pTag);
              $ingTag->appendChild($rTag);

               $ingTag->appendChild($sTag);
               $ingTag->appendChild($tTag);




              $rootTag->appendChild($dataTag);
              $xml->save('asd.xml');
              }

      ?>
```

Comment: theres no way that the outcome you wrote comming from this code... (unless outcome is exactly like that in file `asd.xml`, if so then the code do nothing at all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$source = [['name' => 'name 1', 'quantity' => 'quantity 1'],
         ['name' => 'name 2', 'quantity' => 'quantity 2'],
         ['name' => 'name 3', 'quantity' => 'quantity 3']];

$xml = new DOMDocument ('1.0','UTF-8');

$list = $xml->createElement('list');

foreach($source as $data){
    $ing = $xml->createElement('ing');
    $ing->appendChild($xml->createElement('name', $data['name']));
    $ing->appendChild($xml->createElement('quantity', $data['quantity']));
    $list->appendChild($ing);
}

$xml->appendChild($list);

$xml->save('out.xml');
```